# Is there any iOS device orientation notification in mac programming?

Tags: macos, xcode6.1

I want to know is there any notification we get when the device connected to macbook has tilted, as I want to implement iOS screen recording feature in my app. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you found the answer yet?